# No module named "xxx" in my project root folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

My project is organized this way:

```
ezrename/
├── base/
├── Images/
└── shell
```

There are empties **init**.py files in ezrename, base and shell folders. Images is just a resource folder and don't have anything.

I have a module named ezrename/base/colors.py file, which implements the Colors class.

I have a module named ezrename/shell/baseshell.py, which implements the BaseShell class and imports Colors.

> from ezrename.base import Colors

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devaneando/Development/ezrename/shell/baseshell.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ezrename.base import Colors
ImportError: No module named 'ezrename'
```

So I decided to try

```
from ..base import Colors
```

And gets

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devaneando/Development/ezrename/shell/baseshell.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..base import Colors
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Can somebody explain how the imports works and what am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the pythonic way, I think my idea was wrong. You can't import from two modules as I wanted to because imports will only work if the module itself was not imported do what I wanted is not possible.

The pythonic way would be create an application folder without an **init**.py file, import the package in the application entrance script and the the relative imports will work:

```
EzRename
└──ezrename/
    ├── base/
    ├── Images/
    └── shell
```

In EzRename, add a application.py:

> import ezrename

If you do that, the relative imports from the classes in shell and base will work. That was the missing piece

Answer (score 0):

Python imports will work form the root of your project, so any imports in modules in subdirectories should import relative to that

So if you're running from a main module in ezrename/ then the import in baseshell.py should be:

`from base import colors`

Comment: Enclosing your code snippets in backticks ` will format them as such - makes things clearer for readers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ezrename/base to the python path and then just import Colors

e.g. from ezrename/shell/baseshell.py

```
import os
import sys
shell_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ezrename_dir = os.path.dirname(shell_dir)
base_dir = os.path.join(ezrename_dir, "base")
sys.path.append(base_dir)
import Colors
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.